# Show if $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(\sin(x))}{x}$ exists, with product/quotient/substitution rules

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Show if $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(\sin(x))}{x}$ exists, if so determine its value.

We have to use the product-rule and quotient-rule etc. to show this.

I thought this didn't exist, but my solution book says it does(without any explanation).

Here's why I thought it wouldn't exist:

Since $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sin(x)=0$ and $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \sin(y)=0$ , using the substitution-rule gives us $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sin(\sin(x))=0$.

We also know $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x}$ diverges.
So when using the product rule, we find  $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(\sin(x))}{x}$ doesn't exist.

I don't know where I went wrong here.

Comment: Which is exactly the "product-rule"? Roughly speaking, $0 \cdot \infty$ is not determined, it may diverge, or it may exist. Also, can you use the known limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$?

Comment: Apply l'Hôpital's rule!

Comment: when $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) =\lambda$ and  $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x) =b$  then  $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)g(x) =\lambda b $ . You can't really use this I suppose, since it doesn't exist, but when you can't  use any of the rules how can you determine them?

Comment: @JanEerland, Thanks, that was my first guess too, but we can't use that one either :(

Comment: @user423841 Can you use the known limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$?

Comment: @MiguelAtencia I guess I'd have to prove that first, but I'll try to use it! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the OP is not allowed to use L'Hôpital's rule, the following known limit can be used:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \sin x}{  x}=1
$$

If we multiply numerator and denominator by $\sin x$ we obtain:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin (\sin x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x \sin (\sin x)}{x \sin x}
$$
Now compute the two limits:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \sin (\sin x)}{ \sin x}=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{ \sin y}{ y}=1
$$
where we have called $y=\sin x$, and:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \sin x}{  x}=1
$$
and apply the product rule, which is now allowed because *both* limits exist.

Comment: Sorry, but can we multiply or divide by $0$?

Comment: smart answer. (+1)

Comment: @TheDeadLegend: as you are computing a limit, $x\ne0$.

Comment: Nowhere do we divide by $0$. in the limit, we have $x\to0$ not $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to use the product rule *when the limits of the factors exist*, which is not the case here. Your use of the rule is invalid.

Actually, this is a $\dfrac00$ undeterminate form that you may not rewrite as $$\lim\frac00=\lim0\cdot\lim\frac10.$$

---

On the opposite, the solution given by Miguel Atencia is valid because in

$$\lim\frac{\sin(\sin(x))}{x}=\lim\frac{\sin(\sin(x))}{\sin(x)}\cdot\lim\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$ both limits exist (and are $1$).